# How to display month and week days in other languages in AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, date, internationalization

Is there a way to display month and week days names in a language different to English with AppEngine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Python runtime, [locale is unavailable](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=992), but [Django 1.2](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django) templates support [format localization](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/i18n/localization/#format-localization).

Comment: Hi Drew, do you have any suggestion for who does not use Django? I'm using web.py and can't find a good way to make my date formatting localized.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is. Just use correct Locale. For example:

```
    Date now = new Date();
    DateFormat monthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM", Locale.FRENCH);
    String currentMonth = monthFormat.format(now);
```

Day names are accessible via similar pattern. Other example:

```
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, Locale.GERMAN);
    String date = df.format(now);
```

However, I would recommend using DEFAULT pattern:

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
            DateFormat.DEFAULT, DateFormat.DEFAULT, Locale.ITALIAN);
    String defaultDateTime = dateFormat.format(now);
```

As you can see it works just like in other Java based applications. That is unless you were asking for Python-based GAE...

Comment: So sorry I forgot to mention it was for Python! Thanks a lot anyway!